# Does an HEV Genset need a controller?

Tags: motor, dc, generator, motor-controller, alternator

I am part of a team at school that designs and builds a hybrid electric vehicle. We have chosen to use a series hybrid configuration, so we will be using a motor as a generator to charge lithium polymer batteries, which will be connected to a battery management system. We are likely going to be using a brushed DC motor as the generator, which will be connected to a small engine that will be running at a constant rpm and I'm trying to figure out if a controller is necessary for this generating motor and if not, what is the best option? Also what needs to be regulated before reaching the battery?

Comment: You'll need a way to detect when the LiPo batteries are fully charged, for one. You can get charge controller ICs which handle this for you - the [MCP73833](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en027785) is a common one. You'll probably also want to ensure that they're properly balance-charged if you're using multi-cell LiPo batteries, which I suspect you will be.

Comment: You'll need a LiPo Charge controller.

Comment: The battery will be connected to a BMS so is a charge controller connected to the generator neccesary? Also what about controlling safety-critical aspects?